# Remuestreo con datos fijos

Tags: r, bucles

Disculpad por lo simple de este ejemplo. Es la primera vez que escribo por aquí y espero saber explicarme. Por simplicidad, pongo un ejemplo con un número de variables, observaciones, y valores sencillos.

Estoy intentando hacer una regresión lineal en R de forma iterativa (similar a bootstrapping) en la que quiero: por una parte, disminuir el tamaño de la muestra en cada regresión, y al mismo tiempo reemplazar los datos, pero **sólo una parte de los datos**. Por ejemplo, dada una muestra de variables Y, X1 Y X2, con 100 observaciones cada una:

```
#obs  1 2 3 4 5 ... 100

Y     1  2  3  4  5 ... 100

X1    5  5  5  5  5 ... 5  

X2    51 52 53 54 55 ... 150
```

Lo que quiero es realizar una regresión lineal de forma iterativa (50 repeticiones) con 10 observaciones en cada regresión, de las cuales, las 5 primeras quiero que sean **SIEMPRE** las observaciones 1 a 5, y que las 5 observaciones restantes sean tomadas de forma aleatoria entre las observaciones 6 a 100. Y así de forma repetida.

El código que estoy empleando es el siguiente:

```
library(readr)
mydata <- data.frame(Y = c(1:99,1), X1 = rep(5,100), X2 = seq(51,150))
statistic <- function(mydata, index) {
  lm.fit <- lm(Y ~ X1 + X2, data = mydata, subset = index)
  coef(lm.fit)
}

newrows = c(1:5, 6:100) #divido los datos en dos grupos: las 5 primeras observaciones por un lado, y el resto por otro lado
newdata <- mydata[newrows, ] #renombro el conjunto de datos

B = 50 # número de iteraciones del bucle
matriz_coeficientes <- matrix(NA, nrow = B, ncol = 2) #matriz para guardar los coeficientes de las iteraciones
ajuste_modelo <- numeric() #vector para guarda el ajuste del modelo de las iteraciones
for(i in 1:B) {
  sample <- newdata[sample(1:100, 10, replace = TRUE), ]
  lm.fit <- lm(Y ~ X1 + X2, data = sample)
  matriz_coeficientes[i,] <- coef(lm.fit)
  ajuste_modelo[i] <- summary(lm(Y ~ X1 + X2, data = sample)
  )$r.squared
}
```

Al dividir los datos en dos bloques, no estoy segura de si en el resampleo cada vez que se inicia el bucle estoy tomando las 5 primeras observaciones más otras 5 de entre el resto de forma aleatoria, o si por el contrario estoy tomando siempre 10 observaciones de forma aleatoria de entre las 100, sin mantener las 5 primeras fijas.

Gracias por vuestra ayuda!!

Answer (score 0):

bienvenida!

Creo que encontré una solución, que es una adaptación del código que uso para hacer bootstrap a mano. Es una aproximación más de programación funcional, no uso un bucle sino una función replicadora (rerun), genero una lista de modelos y luego paso sobre esa lista para extraer los coeficientes u otras cantidades de interés.

```
library(tidyverse) #Para rerun y %>% 

mydata <- data.frame(Y = c(1:99,1), 
                     X1 = rnorm(100, 0, 1),   #Cambie a normal aleatorio pq si es constante lm() se queja
                     X2 = seq(51,150))
```

Separo al df en dos partes, una que estará siempre o otra que es una población desde la que muestrearé

```
constante <- slice(mydata, 1:5) 
población <- slice(mydata, 6:nrow(mydata))
```

rerun(n, ...) replica n veces la expresión en ... y lo organiza en una lista

```
rerun(10, 
      bind_rows(                  #Pego las filas
        constante,                #de lo que va en todos los casos
        sample_n(población, 5, replace = FALSE)    #y una muestra de n=5 sin reemplazo desde el objeto población
        ) %>% 
        lm(Y~X1+X2, data = .)) ->     #Ajusto el modelo, como uso %>% indico que los datos son .
  muchos_modelos                      #Le pongo nombre al output
```

Ahora puede consultar a mis modelos que están en la lista. Por ejemplo, extraer una matriz de coeficientes:

```
  sapply(muchos_modelos, coef)        #Paso por la lista y aplica la función coef para extraer los estimados, sapply organiza el output en una matriz
```

El resultado

> Presento solo 10 modelos, pero se podría extender hasta donde alcance la RAM

```
                     [,1]          [,2]          [,3]          [,4]          [,5] [,6]          [,7]          [,8]          [,9]         [,10]
(Intercept) -5.000000e+01 -5.000000e+01 -5.000000e+01 -5.000000e+01 -5.000000e+01  -50 -5.000000e+01 -5.000000e+01 -5.000000e+01 -5.000000e+01
X1           1.669652e-14 -9.784395e-15 -1.064692e-14 -1.305576e-14  3.784322e-15    0 -9.112859e-15 -1.729514e-15 -7.458919e-15  2.484022e-15
X2           1.000000e+00  1.000000e+00  1.000000e+00  1.000000e+00  1.000000e+00    1  1.000000e+00  1.000000e+00  1.000000e+00  1.000000e+00
```

Una matriz en la que cada fila es un coeficiente y cada columna un modelo. Se puede usar `t()` para transponerla y que cada filas sea un modelo.

O el estadístico de varianza explicada

```
  sapply(muchos_modelos, function(modelo) summary(modelo)$r.squared)
```

La ventaja que le encuentro es que como se va creando la estructura de datos paso a paso es más fácil verificar que todo esté funcionando como esperamos.

De hecho se podría hacer más paso-a-paso, crear primero una lista data frames con los remuestreos y verificar si está bien. Luego sobre lista ajustar los modelos y asignarles nombres, luego sobre la lista de modelos sacar las cantidades de interés.

Es consistente con aquello de "Fold knowledge into data so program logic can be stupid and robust." Además soy muy malo escribiendo bucles;)